# I select list of emails as string and want to save them as json or javascript object in mogodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, javascript-objects

I select multiple users emails and get something like that:

```
"participants" : "brian@thirdroute.com,nikola@tesla.com,someone@gmail.com",
```

But want to save them as a javascript or json object or array to later I can track each email.
I want something like that:

```
    "participants" : "{
                   {email:brian@thirdroute.com}, 
                   {email:nikola@tesla.com} 
                  }
```

I need to track all these emails separately and do something with this emails later. For selecting multiple user I used selectize.js where i can tags list of emails.

Answer (score 0):

```
 participants = participants.split(",").map(email => ({email}));
```

Just split the email string into an array of strings, than map them to the objects.

Comment: Thansk i tried this way but my backend support is keystone.js which do not works with => signs. I do not know why. I solved it another way.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it this way:

```
var participants = "brian@thirdroute.com, nikola@tesla.com, someone@gmail.com";     
var arr = participants.split(',');
        // console.log(arr[0]);
        var i;
        var participantsArr = [];
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            participantsArr.push({ email: arr[i] });
        }
        var objparticipantsArr = JSON.stringify(participantsArr);
        console.log(objparticipantsArr);
```

So the result is like:

```
[{"email": "email1@gmail.com"}, {"email": "email2@gmail.com"}, {"email": "email3@gmail.com"}]
```